# Random character strange defined behavior

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings, srand

I'm using an array in this code because i need a string which should be always modified, that's why i'm not using a pointer, howewer everytime i run the code i get a strange behavior at the 31th iteration.

code

```
int i = 0;
char name[100];
srand(getpid());


while(i<100) {

    name[i] += (char)'A'+(rand()%26);
    printf("%d strlen\n", i+1);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("/////\n");
    i++;    
}
```

output

```
/////
30 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOY
/////
31 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJ
/////
32 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJWttime
/////
33 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJW�time
/////
34 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJW��ime
/////
35 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJW���me
/////
36 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJW����e
/////
37 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJW�����
```

In other words it prints always `ttime` as the 31th character and then the code overwrites each character of that word and i get question mark as a result.

Going on the things get even worse look at the final output

```
100 strlen
IKXVKZOLKHLTKBFFTUZCYXHYVEBZOYJW�����K��ȶ������MKRLHALEV�SNNRVWNOEXUVQNJUHAEWN�W�YPMCW�N�PXHNT��0�
/////
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `name` is not `0`-out before the game starts, then is treated as a C-string: The infamous Undefined Behaviour strikes again.

Comment: I'm betting you have prior experience with other languages. C strings are weird – but predictable. `string += 'x'` does not do what you think.

Comment: @alk what do you mean by it is not 0-out before the game starts?

Comment: @usr2564301 you're right that way works better but still prints some undefined characters

Comment: Because it does not do what you think it does... Look up "strings" in your favorite C handbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are printing garbage value. What the behavior will be is not known.(Undefined behavior) By that I mean, it may be the case that those garbage values (added with your random number) may be ascii values of some characters or may be those are some non-printables. You should initialize the char array (with `\0`'s - that will serves two purpose, Providing `\0` for the running string and also you can add and be sure it will be a printable) or **just assign it**.

```
name[i] = 'A'+(rand()%26);
```

Also put a `\0` in the end of the string. Otherwise it will try to access array index out of bound until it finds `\0` and it will invoke undefined behavior.

`31` is not something special - it can be anything the very next time you run it.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char name[100]={0}; // = "";
    srand(getpid());

    while(i<99) { // till 99 making sure you won't overwrite the last NUL

        name[i] ='A'+(rand()%26);
        printf("%d strlen\n", i+1);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        printf("/////\n");
        i++;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that we have looped till `98`th index because there is NUL terminating character in the `99`th index.

Answer (score 1):

`char name[100];` is not a string by default. It is just another 100 element `char` array.

In C a string is a ***always*** carrying (at least) one `'\0'` character to mark the end of the string. `printf()`, mostly all `str*()` functions and many other functions rely on this terminating `'\0'`.

Also what is the idea behind adding to the array elements?

```
  name[i] += ...
```

Their values are not set, they are garbage. Even worth, adding to them means reading uninitialised memory 1st, which in turn provokes undefined behaviour.

So to fix your code drop the addition add the terminator by hand:

```
while (i < 99) {
  name[i] = (char) 'A' + (rand() % 26);
  name[i + 1] = '\0';
```

Or go for the lazy approach any initialising `name` to all `'\0'` even before starting:

```
char name[100] = ""; /* or ... = {0}; */
```

(this would allow you to stick to doing `name[i] += ...`. Still, as all elements are `0`, adding is of no use.)

In ***any*** case do not loop until the array last element (100 here), but always one less as the last element is reserved for the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: thanks you're solution it's right indeed, i voted the other one just because he answered before

Answer (score 0):

If the `char name[100]` array is a local variable inside a function, its initial value is undefined. So  it will contain whatever random junk was in that chunk of memory before.

Therefore when you are doing

```
name[i] += (char)'A'+(rand()%26);
```

you are actually doing

```
name[i] = RANDOM JUNK + (char)'A'+(rand()%26);
```